# Research on lower bounds of sphericity of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I am looking for references that address lower bounds on the "sphericity" of a graph.

> For a finite point set in Euclidean $n$-space, if we connect each pair
> of points by a line segment whenever the distance between them is less
> than a certain positive constant, we obtain a space graph in $n$-space.
> The sphericity of a graph $G$ is defined to be the minimum number $n$ such
> that $G$ is isomorphic to a space graph in $n$-space. [1]

There are several which address *upper* bounds on this quantity, such as [1], and also papers like [2] which address the relation between sphericity and cubicity, but are there any that address lower bounds for certain classes of graphs?

**Edit:** I also found a paper addressing lower bounds on the *boxicity* of certain classes of graphs [3], but it was recently published in 2014, which suggests to me that this is an under-researched area.

[1] Maehara, H. (1984). Space graphs and sphericity. Discrete Applied Mathematics, 7(1), 55–64. https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(84)90113-6

[2] Fishburn, P. C. (1983). On the sphericity and cubicity of graphs. Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series B, 35(3), 309–318. https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(83)90057-6

[3] Adiga, A., Chandran, L. S., & Sivadasan, N. (2014). Lower bounds for boxicity. Combinatorica, 34(6), 631–655. https://doi.org/10.1007/s00493-011-2981-0